# Flutter Firestore ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods, x86-64, flutter-dependencies, podfile

I am trying to apply a patch to reduce build times for an ios 14.4 flutter app.

The patch works by editing the ios podfile to consume pre-compiled binaries for specific packages, instead of downloading the entire firebase SDK and searching for what is needed.

The fix is applied by modifying FirebaseFirestore Pod to redirect to a github repo, and by editing the post_install routine to replace the minimum os version with what is compatible with Xcode. The full podfile is as follows:

```
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '7.3.0'
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end
end
```

Making these changes results in a build fail error, with a long chain of plugin depreciation warnings, warnings that file Pods are being ignored, and Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 with examples as follows

- depreciation warning:

/Users/administrator/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-3.2.4/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:102:32: warning: 'authorizationStatus' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 14.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
authorizationStatus
In module 'CoreLocation' imported from /Users/administrator/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-3.2.4/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:4:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/Headers/CLLocationManager.h:218:1: note: 'authorizationStatus' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
+ (CLAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatus API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("-authorizationStatus", ios(4.2, 14.0), macos(10.7, 11.0), watchos(1.0, 7.0), tvos(9.0, 14.0));
^

- Pod ignored:

ld: warning: ignoring file Pods/FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore/BoringSSL-GRPC.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/BoringSSL-GRPC.framework/BoringSSL-GRPC, missing required architecture x86_64 in file Pods/FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore/BoringSSL-GRPC.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/BoringSSL-GRPC.framework/BoringSSL-GRPC (2 slices)

- Undefined symbols:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_FIRFirestoreErrorDomain", referenced from:
___63-[FLTTransactionStreamHandler onListenWithArguments:eventSink:]_block_invoke in cloud_firestore(FLTTransactionStreamHandler.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRSnapshotMetadata", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreWriter.o)

I'm new to flutter/xcode programming so I am struggling to make sense of this error output, and to determine what information is relevant to finding the solution. Any help would be much appreciated.